# What type of JOIN to use? mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query where all products sold are being selected. What I want to do is reverse the query and get all product not sold within a period of time.

This is the query for all the products sold within a period of time.

```
 SELECT 
    product.product_id, 
    product.product_brand_id, 
    product.product_model_id, 
    product.product_subcategory_id, 
    product.product_retail_price, 
    product.product_wholesale_price, 
    product.product_aretail_price, 
    product.product_awholesale_price, 
    product.product_oretail_price, 
    product.product_owholesale_price,  
    product.product_quoted_price, 
    product.product_aquoted_price, 
    product.product_dquoted_price, 
    product_sold.product_type, SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) AS product_quantity_sold, SUM(product_sold.product_total_price) AS total_price_sold
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_sold 
    ON product.product_id = product_sold.product_id 
    AND product.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
INNER JOIN sales
    ON sales.sales_id = product_sold.product_sales_id 
WHERE sales.sales_approved = '1' 
    AND sales.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' 
    AND sales.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
GROUP BY product_sold.product_type, product.product_id 
ORDER BY SUM(product_sold.product_quantity) DESC
```

Can someone guide me on how to get unsold products, im kinda stock here with no ideas.  Thanks.

ANSWER:

```
                SELECT 
                    p.product_id, 
                    p.product_brand_id, 
                    p.product_model_id, 
                    p.product_subcategory_id, 
                    p.product_retail_price, 
                    p.product_wholesale_price, 
                    p.product_aretail_price, 
                    p.product_awholesale_price, 
                    p.product_oretail_price, 
                    p.product_owholesale_price, 
                    p.product_quoted_price, 
                    p.product_aquoted_price, 
                    p.product_dquoted_price,
                    pq.product_stock_type
                FROM 
                    product p
                LEFT JOIN 
                    product_sold ps 
                ON 
                    p.product_id = ps.product_id
                INNER JOIN
                    product_stock pq
                ON
                    p.product_id = pq.product_id
                AND 
                    pq.product_quantity > 0
                WHERE 
                    p.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
                AND
                    ps.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Does your listing of products not sold need to take account of sales where `sales_approved` is not `'1'`?  From your question, it looks you have some subtlety in your business rule about whether a sale is completed. Please explain.

Comment: You're using a nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. You appear to be using the extension correctly, but if you were to change up your query you might start misusing it. Read this, and please be careful:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: I have all product sold in a different table and each time a sales is created gets record on sales table. Once sells gets completed I update product sold with the sales aproved time, that way i dont have to join with sales table anymore to see if a product has been sales approved. Sales pending get marked with 0, aproved with 1, cancelled with 2.  Thanks for the text it will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the way to get members of set A that are not included in set B is to use a left join.  I'll start by simplifying your query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, ps.product_id from product p
LEFT JOIN product_sold ps
WHERE ps.product_id IS NULL
```

This will return all product records that don't have a value in product_sold.  You should be able to add the detail in from there.

Comment: So far so good, thanks for the help. I update my question with the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    product.product_id
FROM product 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                product.product_id
            FROM product
            INNER JOIN product_sold 
                ON product.product_id = product_sold.product_id 
                AND product.product_subcategory_id = '$subcategory_id'
            INNER JOIN sales
                ON sales.sales_id = product_sold.product_sales_id 
            WHERE sales.sales_approved = '1' 
                AND sales.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp' 
                AND sales.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
            GROUP BY product_sold.product_type, product.product_id
        ) AS psold
            ON product.product_id = psold.product_id
WHERE psold.product_id IS NULL
```

With this, you have a subrequest with products sold and you join it with all products, the WHERE clause selects only products that are in the first table (all products) and not in the second (sold products).

Comment: You probably don't need to do the nested SELECT query, and if you don't it's better to avoid it for performance reasons.

Comment: @BobRodes I agree with you, but here I don't know the exact structure of the few tables we have and how to know exactly if a product has been sold or not, so I re-use his initial request.

Comment: I didn't mean to call your reasoning into question, but if the OP doesn't yet understand left joins, he might get the idea that using the nested select is required to solve his problem, and then go about using the technique all the time.  So I thought it might be a good idea to point it out.  :)